# What are some good open source UI Testing tools for testing Windows GUI?

Tags: automated-testing, gui, windows

I need a list of some good tools which are open source and meant for automating the UI testing of Windows GUI. Any help will certainly be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Isn't http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools enough? Why not?

Comment: Does it need to be open source or will free work for you? There is a very limited list of "good" open source UI tools for windows.

Comment: Is TwinTool opensource ? Advance Thanks,
Kishan Patel

Comment: I want to start my career on automation tool. I have started by install Twin & Twin jar on Eclipse Luna. Therefore, I need to discuss. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

**Sikilu**:

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

Comment: Sikuli can be very useful for UI's that are not exposed enough to test via reflection, etc.  Examples include Flash/Flex based apps.  
Performance is not stellar, code is primarily Java, although it can be used in ruby code if you run on Jruby.

Answer (score 9):

**TestStack White**: (partial open-source)

> [White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) is an open-source framework for automating rich client
>   applications based on Win32, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight and SWT (Java)
>   platforms. It is .NET based and does not require the use of any
>   proprietary scripting languages. Tests/automation programs using White
>   can be written with whatever .NET language, IDE and tools you are
>   already using. White provides a consistent object-oriented API, hiding
>   the complexity of [Microsoft's UIAutomation library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107(v=vs.110).aspx) (on which
>   White is based) and windows messages.

With the free [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) you can create automated tests with the .Net framework. See my example console C# app code to automate notepad.exe below:

```cs
using System;
using TestStack.White;
using TestStack.White.InputDevices;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.MenuItems;
using TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems;

namespace WhiteTest
{
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Tests tests = new Tests();
            tests.Notepad();
        }
    }

    class Tests {
        public void Notepad() {
            // Arrange
            Application app = Application.Launch("notepad.exe");
            Window window = app.GetWindow("Untitled - Notepad");

            // Act
            var box = window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByClassName("Edit"));
            Keyboard.Instance.Send("test", box);

            window.MenuBar.MenuItem("File", "Save As...").Click();
            var filename = window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByClassName("Edit"));
            Keyboard.Instance.Send(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff") + "test.txt", filename);
            window.Get(SearchCriteria.ByText("Save")).Click();

            app.Kill();

            // Assert 
            //  file is created in Documents folder
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a newer answer to this question, so give the state of things as of Feb 2019... I would say [Appium](http://appium.io/), Microsoft is deprecating their Coded UI Testing tools and suggests using Appium + WinAppDriver.

From [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2019):

> Coded UI Test for automated UI-driven functional testing is deprecated. Visual Studio 2019 is the last version where Coded UI Test will be available. We recommend using Selenium for testing web apps and Appium with WinAppDriver for testing desktop and UWP apps.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [robot framework](http://www.robotframework.org) with the [autoit](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/) library. Robot is a keyword driven acceptance testing framework, which allows you to write your tests in a very readable, english-like format. Robot files are plain text so they integrate well with version control, and there is a robot format [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin) for jenkins to support continuous integration. Robot also has a nice mechanism for tagging tests, and generates both xml and html reports and logs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add [FlaUI](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI) to the list. It is basically a complete rewrite of White with more flexibility, more features, built-in caching and such.

Answer (score 1):

Katalon Studio supports Windows 10 application testing. From [v 7.0](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/new/version-70.html#version-70-beta) (currently in beta).

I belive it is Winium based.

More info here: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/introduction-desktop-app-testing.html#windows-execution-type.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on SilkTest and it is good. Also, as @Ankit mentioned there are many good UI testing tools, you can find here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools

I would like to add another one named Watir. Used it in one project for data scraping long back and found it helpful.

Watir (Web Application Testing in Ruby, pronounced water), is an open-source family of Ruby libraries for automating web browsers.[1][2][3][4] It drives Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari, and is available as a RubyGems gem.[4][5] Watir was primarily developed by Bret Pettichord and Paul Rogers. (Source: Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir)

Comment: The question is about "Open Source" tools. SilkTest is not open source. :)

Comment: I missed "Open Source", thank you for the correction :)

Comment: As for Silk Test Classic and Silk4Net, I came here searching for alternatives, finding it hard, unintuitive and also highly text-dependent with little room for customization. It probably works ok or even good if you are just using the recorder and editing a bit, but if you want to be a bit more flexible, e. g. with maintaining object maps or embedding into larger context, it seems not straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one project on codeplex.com for automating the UI testing of Windows GUI, among all the other stuff there.

I have been using "UIAutomation Powershell Extensions" 
https://uiautomation.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Twin is a tool for automating Windows graphical applications.The design is based on the web automation tool Selenium/WebDriver, and it can be used in similar ways. Grid 2.0 from webdriver was designed with TWIN in mind, so you can test against multiple virtual machines with different OS installed and let grid 2.0 install the last version of the AUT and route the tests to the correct VM.
You can explore and download it from here:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/twin/

Answer (score 0):

I've used both TestStack White (for controlling a windows app) - which was simple and straightforward to use - and Appium (for controlling Android).

Out of the two, I'd probably go for Appium if the app dev environment wasn't C# - I'm using Specflow as a BDD environment on top of Appium (ironically, I'm developing my android test frameworks in C#) and it's a great combination.