# What is the best free automation tool for Windows applications

Tags: test-automation-framework, ms-uiautomation

What is the best free automation tool for Windows application using object ID's. So *NOT* with keystrokes and x,y coordinates.

Comment: The duplicate also contains some frameworks that use objects instead of images and coordinates, like TestStack White: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/9201/3201

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to automate *generic* Windows apps without sending keystrokes and mouseclicks. (But if I am wrong, I am looking forward to learn something)

Only the method on how you find the position for the click makes the difference:

- via x/y (any tool can do this)
- via objectID/Windows titles/... (e.g. AHK, TestStack White,...)
- via images (e. g. Sikuli or Kantu)